# CARTO.js (V4) - How to style different values of a polygon

Tags: carto, carto-js

Using Carto.js V4, I have added a layer that shows fire risk levels (low, medium, high and extreme) for South Africa.

[image]

This is the code I have used to call the layer from my Carto library:

> const veldfireDataset = new carto.source.Dataset(
>           `veldfire_risk_2010`
>   );
>         const veldfireStyle = new carto.style.CartoCSS(
>           `#layer {
>           polygon-fill: #162945;
>             polygon-opacity: 0.5;
>             ::outline {
>               line-width: 1;
>               line-color: #FFFFFF;
>               line-opacity: 0.5;
>             }
>           }`
>   ); 
>         const veldfire = new carto.layer.Layer(veldfireDataset, veldfireStyle);

How do I fill the polygon depending on the "overall" column's value? And ultimately also add a legend to explain what each colour relates to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to try to make that map using BUILDER and then copy the resulting CartoCSS on your code. You can also learn more about CartoCSS and TurboCARTO on this [guide](https://carto.com/learn/guides/styling/style-thematic-maps-with-turbocarto/).

Regarding legends, have you checked CARTO.js documentation? There's an explicit example on [how to work with legends](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-legends).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of using the code from the builder - it worked perfectly! I will also take a look at the legend example, I should be able to figure it out as now I have my layer styling sorted out.